# grep command doesn't support start '^' and '$' end of line anchors when it's with -Pz

Tags: grep, bugs

With reference of [this Q&A on AU](https://askubuntu.com/q/551338/283843).

Why behavior of GNU `grep` using `-Pz` parameters changed and doesn't support start of line `^` and `$` end of line anchors?

Is this a bug or correct behavior?

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel version 4.4.0-21-generic.

```
$ echo ^ | grep -Pz ^
grep: unescaped ^ or $ not supported with -Pz
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is desired behavior of GNU grep version 2.24 (released on March 10 2016) and above, and that's the fix for the bug which was introduced in GNU grep 2.5.

[Looking into the source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/pcresearch.c#n136):

```c
if (*p == '$' || (*p == '^' && !after_unescaped_left_bracket))
  die (EXIT_TROUBLE, 0,
       _("unescaped ^ or $ not supported with -Pz"));
```

This change was made on Feb 21 2016, see [this bug report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22655) for more details about this change.

---

Though that's GNU grep choice, it's a bug, as GNU grep [compiles the PCRE regex with `PCRE_MULTILINE` set](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/pcresearch.c#n109), and [also reverted to calling pcre_exec for more than one record at a time](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22655#47), which is source of problem, [as pointed out](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22655#47) by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas)

Comment: Shame, sounds like the wrong (non-)fix to the wrong problem. `grep` is calling `pcre_compile` with PCRE_MULTILINE which was the source of the problem in the first place AFAICT (as already noted at https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16871#8)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good point, the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/pcresearch.c#n109) confirm that behavior. Thanks.

Comment: [I've asked for the bug to be reopened](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22655#47)

Comment: @KasiyA, it's now fixed properly in the latest development version (git head). Cuong, it's not as simple as PCRE_MULTILINE being used, it's also that GNU grep had reverted to calling pcre_exec for more than one record at a time. See the [discussion at the bug](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22655#47) for more details. My bad for missing the latest parts of the story.